# VBA OnTime with string argument containing apostrophe

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with the following `OnTime` line:

```
Application.OnTime printTaskTimers(UBound(printTaskTimers)), _
 "'PrintTask """ & cRng.Value & """, " & cRng.Offset(0, 1).Value & " '"
```

`cRng.Value` is worksheet name and `cRng.Offset(0, 1).Value` is the number of pages. It works correctly for all normal sheet names, apart from 2 which contain apostrophe. The apostrophe is important and I would rather adjust the code than change worksheet names. Is there any way around it?

Comment: You already know how to escape double quotes in a string. Single quotes are escaped the same way.

Comment: unfortunately I am still not able to create a working piece of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already know how to escape double quotes in a string. Single quotes are escaped the same way.

```
Application.OnTime printTaskTimers(UBound(printTaskTimers)), _
  "'PrintTask """ & Replace(cRng.Value, "'", "''") & """, " & cRng.Offset(0, 1).Value & " '"
```